# Align a 3D line A to the line B

Tags: python, numpy, math

I want to align a line `A (blue)`, which is defined with a 3D start `(S)` and 3D end point `(E)` to the other 3D line `B (red)`, so that the line `A` (does not matter, how it is originally positioned) is parallel to the line `B`, as shown in `Fig.B`

[image]

I know that I have to calculate the angle between two them for that I do:

```
def calcAngleBtw2Lines(self, vec1S, vec1E, vec2S, vec2E):

    # Substract the end point (E) from the start point (S) of the line
    vec1 = np.subtract(vec1E, vec1S)
    vec2 = np.subtract(vec2E, vec2S)

    # Dot product to get the cosine of the rotation angle
    dotProduct = np.dot(vec1, vec2)

    # Normalize the vectors to find the unit vectors
    vec1Unit = np.linalg.norm(vec1)
    vec2Unit = np.linalg.norm(vec2)

    # Find the angle between vectors
    angle = np.degrees(np.arccos(dotProduct / (vec1Unit * vec2Unit)))
    print("angle: ", angle)

    return np.round(angle, 1)
```

But I am not sure, whether the steps are correct. If they are parallel to each other, the angle between them should be `0`

**Edit:**
The length of both lines are equal. The line B is stationary. To make line A parallel to the B, the S and E of A can be moved at the same time.

Comment: You don't have to calculate the angle for that; just make it so the vector's coordinates are proportional... That said, your question if far from clear: you want A to be parallel to B, but I imagine you want to keep some parameters of A (else why not set A = B and be done with it...): which ones ?

Comment: I can not set A = B. The B is stationary but I want to check each time if A and B are parallel if the S or E of A is changed.

Comment: Do you want to MAKE A and B parallel, or to check WHETHER they are? The title of your question suggests the former.

Comment: I want to make A and B parallel by moving only A.

Comment: Then, as I said earlier, indicate clearly what you mean by "moving A": do you want to move E and S, only E, only S, keep the length, whatever... Please state your constraints clearly!

Comment: I can move E or S of A. The length of A or B can not be changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250150/discussion-between-swifty-and-mystic-06).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a working answer. Note that if A and B have the same lengths, part of the code is unnecessary (but I'll leave it anyway to make it more portable):

```
import numpy as np

def makeAparalleltoB(pointSA, pointEA, pointSB, pointEB):
# pointSA... are np.arrays of the 3 coordinates

    # Calculating the coordinates of the vectors
    vecA = pointEA - pointSA
    vecB = pointEB - pointSB

    # Calculating the lengths of the vectors
    # Unnecessary if we know that A and B have the same lengths
    vecANorm = np.linalg.norm(vecA)
    vecBNorm = np.linalg.norm(vecB)

    # Calculating the coordinates of a vector collinear to B, of the same length as A
    newvecA = vecB * vecANorm/vecBNorm

    # Returning new coordinates for the endpoint of A
    return pointSA + newvecA
```

Example:

```
a = np.array([1,1,1])
b = np.array([2,3,4])
c = np.array([0,0,0])
d = np.array([1,1,1])

print(makeAparalleltoB(a, b, c, d))

# [3.1602469 3.1602469 3.1602469]
```

If we know that A and B have the same length, then it's even simpler: we simply make it so SB, EB, EA, SA is a parallelogram:

```
newpointEA = pointSA + pointEB - pointSB
```

Comment: Why we do not use dot product to measure of how closely two vectors align, in terms of the directions they point and calculate the angle to now how much the A should be moved, so that it is parallel to the B, as I did?

Comment: Because it's unnecessary: for A to be parallel to B, you just have to make sure that the corresponding vectors are collinear, which in turn is equivalent to their coordinates being proportional; so just ensure that the new vector A is a multiple of vector B. Note that if A and B have the same length, it's even simpler: make sure that new vector A = vector B, so just calculate: newpointEA = pointSA + pointEB - pointSB !